# C# How to GetDirectories without 8.3 format names

Tags: c#, directory, directoryinfo, getdirectories

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get a list of directories using a wildcard that doesn't include 8.3 format names.  I'm trying to get all the directories using a wildcard pattern like **"3626*"**.  The problem is both 'Directory.GetDirectories`and`DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories` include long file names and 8.3 format names.  Thus I get entries I don't want.  For example with the above wild card I get both **"3626 Burnt Chimney"** and **"3689 Lavista"**.  You can see the same behavior using a command prompt and the command **"dir 3626*"**.  This is on Windows 7 32 bit.  How can I get only long file names to return?

Comment: Why can't you perform the filter after you retrieve the directories, e.g, `var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Path\").GetDirectories().Select(f => f.FullName).Where(name => name.StartsWith("3626"));`

Comment: Turning short name support off should be a bullet item on every LAN admin's todo list, the feature is entirely without any remaining merit today.  Best way to ensure this doesn't cause trouble is by making sure everybody boots a 64-bit operating system, it cannot run legacy 16-bit code anymore.  That however is rarely up to a programmer, until this happens you need to filter the results in your code.

Comment: @RagtimeWilly, Your syntax was close, d.Name instead of d.FullName, and because I'm looking for directories and not files I changed it a little: `var dirs = new DirectoryInfo(outputFolder).GetDirectories().Select(d => d.Name).Where(name => name.StartsWith(prefix));` This works but I had really wanted to use the Directory class rather than DirectoryInfo because I didn't want the overhead and ended up with this:`var outputDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(outputFolder, prefix + "*").Where(path => Path.GetFileName(path).StartsWith(prefix));`

If you will post as Answer I will mark it.

Comment: @dblwizard Posted as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the filter after you retrieve the directories, e.g,

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Path\")
                   .GetDirectories()
                   .Select(f => f.Name)
                   .Where(name => name.StartsWith("3626"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find some more information here: [List files in folder which match pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739767/list-files-in-folder-which-match-pattern)

The comment from RagtimeWilly is what I also want to suggest.

For a good explanation of 8.3 names see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename

I just wrote a small example, perhaps you can use this as a starting point:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...

Regex re83 = new Regex(@"^[^.]{1,8}(\.[^.]{0,3})?$");

DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\windows");

foreach (string no83 in directoryInfo.GetDirectories("i*").Select(di => di.Name).Where(n => !re83.IsMatch(n)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(no83);
}
```

Searching the web, you find some other regex for matching 8.3 names, some a bit more complex. Some characters are not allowed in 8.3. names, which is handled by those. But you maybe are just interested in filtering out some unwanted path names.

Comment: I fully understood why this was happening just couldn't believe there wasn't some flag or other Method I was missing that would return just long names ... seems like a simple thing.

Comment: I know this situation very well. I often have a working solution and think "is this really such complicated" and search for some simpler or obvious solution :-)